# Heading style in Word adjustment

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

I am using a Heading style in MS Word as follows:

[image: Heading style]

My question is, how you define automatically in the Heading modification to have the second line align with the first one, without using the Left Indent bar. But, rather automatically to all heading 1 style.

Comment: Use a [Hanging Indent](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-hanging-indent-7bdfb86a-c714-41a8-ac7a-3782a91ccad5)

Comment: Once you apply the Hanging Indent as specified by @DavidPostill, you can right click on "Heading 1" and "Update Heading 1 to Match Selection". That will update the style and apply it to all Heading 1 you have on your document.